# Symfony 2 passing array in service.xml

Tags: xml, arrays, symfony, service, connection

I have services in my services.xml

```
<service id="my.connection" class="Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\ConnectionFactory">
</service>

<service id="my.main" class="%my.main.class%">
    <call method="foo">
        <argument type="service" id="tmcyc.connection" />
    </call>
</service>
```

But got error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\ ConnectionFactory::__construct() must
>   be an array, none given...

How can I pass array with argument?
For example:

```
<service id="my.connection" class="Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\ConnectionFactory">
    <argument>[ARRAY]</argument>
</service>
```

or maybe I'm doing somthing wrong? Because this code works greate:

```
$connectionFactory = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory');
$conn = $this->createConnection($this->conn);
$conn->executeQuery('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Еhis example should clarify the principle:

In ***.yml**

```
some_id: 
    class: %some.class%
    arguments: 
        - %some.argument%, 
        - [tags: [environment: %kernel.environment%, debug:%kernel.debug%]]
```

In ***.xml**

```
<service id="some_id" class="%some.class%">
    <argument>%some.argument%</argument>
    <argument type="collection">
        <argument key="tags" type="collection">
            <argument key="environment">%kernel.environment%</argument>
            <argument key="debug">%kernel.debug%</argument>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</service>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, widely more demonstrative.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer

```
<service id="my.connection" class="Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\ConnectionFactory">
    <argument>%doctrine.dbal.connection_factory.types%</argument>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

same with the parameters

In ***.xml**

```
    <parameter key="some.key" type="collection">
        <parameter>parameter 1</parameter>
        <parameter>parameter 2</parameter>
    </parameter>
```